Read state of provider without passing arguments again
Let me preface this that I'm very new to Flutter and coming from Rails where current_user was much simpler to setup.  I'm creating a functional currentUserProvider:
@riverpod
User currentUser(CurrentUserRef ref, User user) {
    User currentUser = user;
    return currentUser;
  }
}

This gets built on successful logins within another provider that checks if the login was successful and saves their state:
enum AuthenticationState {
  initial,
  loading,
  success,
  error,
}

@riverpod
class Authentication extends _$Authentication {
  @override
  AuthenticationState build() {
    return AuthenticationState.initial;
  }

  Future<void> login() async {
    //API Call made here and status returned:
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      User currentUser = User.fromJson((json.decode(response.body))['data']['attributes']);
      currentUser = currentUser.copyWith(jwt: token);
      ref.read(currentUserProvider(user: currentUser));
      state = AuthenticationState.success;
    } else {
      await SecureStorage().deleteSecureData('jwt');
      state = AuthenticationState.error;
    }
  }
}

My problem is that everywhere else going forward, I only want the cached value of the currentUserProvider but it expects me to pass it the user object as a parameter.  I don't want to make the user argument optional since it should never be null and users are redirected to the login screen.  Is there any way to just get the current state of it? I don't want to make params optional because the User object can't be null.

The state of an AsyncNotifier is an instance of AsyncValue<User> which has e.g. methods:

isLoading
isRefreshing
isReloading
hasError, etc

Instead of an authenticationProvider and a currentUserProvider, you could have:
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';

part 'user_notifier.g.dart';

class User {
  const User(this.id);
  final int id;
}

@riverpod
class UserNotifier extends _$UserNotifier {
  @override
  Future<User> build() {  
     return future; // A future that resolves with the first state
                    // that is not of type `AsyncLoading`.
  }

  Future<void> login() async { // Later probably with credentials
    // Set the state to loading
    state = const AsyncValue.loading();
    // Set the state data
    state = await AsyncValue.guard(() async {
      return await Future.delayed(
        const Duration(seconds: 5),
        () => const User(1),
      );
    });
  }

  // This getter might not be required. The information is already
  // available. 
  AuthenticationState get authenticationState {
    if (state.isLoading) {
      return AuthenticationState.loading;
    }else if(state.hasError){
      return AuthenticationState.error;
    }
    ...
  }
}

In the example below, the page initially displays the loading indicator. After clicking login the loading indicator is showing for 5 more seconds  and finally the user id is displayed.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import '../../providers/user_notifier.dart';

class UserPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const UserPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final userAsyncValue = ref.watch(userNotifierProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('User Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: switch (userAsyncValue) {
          AsyncData(value: final user) => Text(user.id.toString()),
          AsyncError(:final error) => Text('Error: $error'),
          _ => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          await ref.read(userNotifierProvider.notifier).login();
        },
        tooltip: 'Log in',
        child: const Icon(Icons.login),
      ), 
    );
  }
}


return await Future.any<User>([]); is simpler as just return future, which returns notifier.future which completes when state is given a different value.  That's the preferred idiom for "born loading".

@RandalSchwartz, thanks, that's useful to know. I have amended the build method.
